# SQLlite Android Database how to auto-delete if max size reached?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, logging

im in the process of building out massive logging for my app.  I could use flat files but before that im considering sqllite db.  I would like to know is there a way to create a database and have it auto delete if a certain byte size on disk is reached ?  I'd also like to do this on the table level.  So if a table size became over a certain max i would wipe the entire table and start clean.  I wanted to know if at the time of creating a table in sql if there is a command i can use to 'trigger' this ?

Comment: Why wiping the entire table? Wouldn't it make more sense to delete only the oldest entries?

Comment: Yes that's also possible.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger something, use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

SQLite has no built-in mechanism to detect the byte size of a table; the best you could do is to count records:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER WipeOnOverflow
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) > 1000
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MyTable;
END;
```

or:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteOneRecordOnOverflow
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) > 1000
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE rowid = (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM MyTable);
END;
```

Comment: yes i know about triggers ..they key concept i was missing is that we can delete based on number of rows ..this answer is acceptable for my cause, thank you.